# SQL error "ORA-01722: invalid number" when trying to filter on the ratio between two user-defined columns

Tags: r, oracle, dbplyr

I have built an app in RShiny. I am trying to allow a user to filter (using dbplyr) a dataframe stored in an Oracle database on whether the ration between two user-defined columns is more than a user-defined percentage. The following code runs, but does not filter the dataframe.

```
      var_2 <- "column_2

      
      my_df <- my_df %>%
        filter({{var_1}} <= {{var_2}})
```

If I then change it to the following code,

```
     var_2 <- "column_2
     ratio_min <- 0.1
     
     my_df <- my_df %>%
       filter({{var_1}} <= ratio_min * {{var_2}})
```

I get the error [RStudio][OracleOCI] (3000) Oracle Caller Interface: ORA-01722: invalid number

However the following code,

```
     var_2 <- "column_2
     ratio_min <- 0.1
     
     my_df <- my_df %>%
       mutate(test_col = ratio_min * {{var_2}})
```

does not give me an error. Also when I filter by comparing any of the individual variables to a number, it filters fine.

Comment: Then, `SELECT value FROM nls_session_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS'` will return `.,`, won't it ? If so retry after setting that parameter to `,.` ( at least for the current session ).

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle documentation ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/error-help/db/ora-01722/)) explains that this error message occurs when attempting and failing to convert character strings to numbers.

This means that in the database, at least one of the columns you are referencing is a character string not a number - most likely `var_2`. Hence when attempting the calculation `ratio_min * var_2` the database attempts a conversion of `var_2` to numeric in order to multiply but is unable to.

A common cause of this is characters like `,` and `.` - the values look like numbers but are actually text:

- Some databases will not convert `12,345,678.9` to numeric because of the commas as thousands separators. (Though they may convert to the money data-type.)
- This similarly causes problems where commas are used to indicate decimals. For example: `0,1234` as equivalent to `0.1234`.

Even if R can handle the conversion correctly, with dbplyr the conversion text-to-number is happening on the database.

I would suggest the following:

1. Figure out what data types are being used in the database
2. Locate at least one example of cell that is failing the conversion to numeric
3. Decide how you want to convert the values to numeric. Potential options:

   - Deliberate text cleaning to remove problematic characters before conversion
   - `TRY_CAST` or equivalent to cast data types only when relevant
   - The suggestion as commented by Barbaros Özhan - if it is a matter of swapping commas and full-stops.